# как проверить подключение к телеграмм в Telethon python

Tags: python, api, telegram, telethon

Есть скрипт на отправку каждые 5 секунд текст в определенный чат, как сделать проверку на то не потерялось ли соединение к телеграмму? Если что скрипт без всяких классов, просто в функцию засунул цикл в котором отправляются сообщения каждые 5 сек.

Comment: ну что то типо `if connected(): print('+)' else: print('-')`

Answer (score 1):

Смысл проверять подключение. Библиотека телеграмма устроена так, что если всё работает, то она ничего не пишет, просто делает свою работу, а если что-то не так она сразу даёт ошибку по типу

> «telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. >Error code: 404 Description: Not Found